# Why Data Type DT_NTEXT from SQL Command OLE DB Source?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, ntext

In our SSIS package, in the Data Flow OLE DB Source Editor, the Connection Manager is a SQL Command, and the SQL Command text is this:

```
With Managers AS (
  select distinct t1.ID,
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ' & ' + t2. MgrName
      from myTableA t2
      where t1.ID = t2.ID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
      ,1,3,'') MgrName
  from myTableA)
select Managers.MgrName as ManagerName
:
FROM myTableB INNER JOIN myTableA 
ON myTableB.ID = myTableB.ID
```

When I right click on the OLE DB Source > Show Advanced Editor > Input and Output Properties, ManagerName’s DataType is Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT].

Why is the DataType DT_NTEXT, and not DT_WSTR or DT_STR ?

The OLE DB Destination (SQL Server database) data type for this is a VARCHAR, so before I can populate the OLE DB Destination I need to do a “Data Conversion” from

```
Unicode text stream [DT_NTEXT]
To 
Unicode string [DT_WSTR]
To
string [DT_WSTR]
```

Comment: Searching on google is easiest then asking on SO!! just search for `nvarchar(max) dt_ntext` and you will find a lot of relevant articles: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5047/import-and-export-varcharmax-data-with-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/

Comment: You could cast `Managers.MgrName` to varchar in your source query, and then you could skip the data conversion task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DT_WSTR` and `DT_STR` have maximum lengths of 4,000 and 8,000 characters respectively. As a result they are too small to be mapped against an `(n)varchar(MAX)` and so `DT_NTEXT` and `DT_TEXT` are used.

Comment: Ah..OK. Thank you for the quick response